# MSBuild can't copy assembly .dll file to $(OutDir)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild-task

Under building simple C# project (only one simple class is defined in it
without functional methods) I get the next error message:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\
Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3528,5): error MSB3024:
Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\G4S_CVisitDescr.dll"
to the destination file "..........\Projects\Server\Debug\G4S_CVisitDescr.dll",
because the destination is a folder instead of a file.
To copy the source file into a folder, consider using the DestinationFolder
parameter instead of DestinationFiles."

This error message is strange because in the relevant fragment of the
.targets file destination parameter of the Copy task is just recommended
in the message DestinationFolder! This fragment (in which the line `"<Copy"`
has number 3528 pointed in the error message) is placed below:

```
<!-- Copy the build product (.dll or .exe). -->
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(IntermediateAssembly)"
    DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="$(SkipCopyUnchangedFiles)"
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
    Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
    RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
    UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible)"
    Condition="'$(CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory)' == 'true' and '$(SkipCopyBuildProduct)' !=                 'true'">
    <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="MainAssembly"/>
    <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
</Copy>
```

It is also strange that another analogous project with the same project
file and the same project properties is built without any error. "Bad"
project is also built without errors if building is invoked by the
method Solution2.SolutionBuild.BuildProject with previous invoking
the Solution2.SolutionBuild.Clean method   or  the "OutputPath" property
has the default value "bin\x86\Debug" under manual invoking (because,
perhaps, no copying is done in this case).

So, I have two next questions:

1) How should I understand the error and how to fix it (if it is possible)?

2) Which difference between the analogous projects may cause the error?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
  Lebyko
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your project->Properties->Build->Events->Pre-build event and add the following two lines, that's fixing the problem

```
if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked"
if exist "$(TargetPath)" if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"
```